# chicken scheme srfi-64 test-error problems

Tags: unit-testing, testing, scheme, chicken-scheme

I am using chicken scheme version 4.9.0.1 and am working on a
unit test suite using the unit test package srfi-64.

I am having trouble with test-error in this unit test package.

A minimal example of the problem:

```
(require-extension srfi-64)
(test-begin "error testing")
(define (exn-tester)
  (error "What does srfi-64 want?"))
(test-error "the exn-tester" 'exn (exn-tester))
(test-end)
```

Results in the report:

```
%%%% Starting test error testing
Group begin: error testing
Test begin:
  test-name: "the exn-tester"
Test end:
  result-kind: fail
  actual-error: #<condition: (exn)>
  expected-error: exn
Group end: error testing
# of unexpected failures  1
```

The problem is clearly in my test-error because I don't know how
to represent the exception in a form that test-error understands.
I've tried multiple variations on the actual-error as listed,
but to no success.

Specifically, what should I code for the expected-error in the 
test-error call?

Answer (score 1):

The SRFI spec itself basically says "it's implementation-dependent", but after a look at the code it seems you can simply pass it a predicate:

```lisp
(require-extension srfi-64)
(test-begin "error testing")
(define (exn-tester)
  (error "What does srfi-64 want?"))
(test-error "the exn-tester" (condition-predicate 'exn) (exn-tester))
(test-end)
```

Please note that in the CHICKEN community, the [test egg](http://wiki.call-cc.org/eggref/4/test) is the facto testing egg. However, it currently has no way to test for a specific exception type. I once wrote this macro for the Postgres egg's test suite:

```
(define-syntax test-error*
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ ?msg (?error-type ...) ?expr)
     (let-syntax ((expression:
                   (syntax-rules ()
                    ((_ ?expr)
                     (condition-case (begin ?expr "<no error thrown>")
                                     ((?error-type ...) '(?error-type ...))
                                     (exn () (##sys#slot exn 1)))))))
      (test ?msg '(?error-type ...) (expression: ?expr))))
   ((_ ?msg ?error-type ?expr)
    (test-error* ?msg (?error-type) ?expr))
   ((_ ?error-type ?expr)
     (test-error* (sprintf "~S" '?expr) ?error-type ?expr))))
```

To be used as follows:

```
 (test-error* "Result value error for out of bounds row"
              (exn postgresql bounds)
              (value-at (query conn "SELECT NULL") 0 1))
```

The `(exn postgresql bounds)` tells the test to accept a composite condition (refer to [SRFI-12](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-12/srfi-12.html) for more info) of the types `exn`, `postgresql` and `bounds`.  It can have other types, but in this example, these three must be present for the test to pass.

Comment: Thank you VERY much for you complete and informative reply.

Answer (score 0):

With your tips, the following works well enough:

```
(require-extension test)

test-begin "error-testing")
(define (exn-tester)
  (error "What does srfi-64 want?"))
(test-error  (exn-tester))
(test-end "error-testing")
```

Attempts to use your define-syntax resulted in "unbound variable: exn".
Perhaps I require additional extension to use this?

However, your define-syntax will warrant future attention. I am only getting started in Scheme and, having a test driven background, am most interested in my code being the very best.

Comment: hm, maybe the definition contains a bug. Can you paste the full code that fails?